# How can use in_array match or not match codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-7

I use codeigniter. i fetch all mark . i want check that every subject i mean gpa = F or not. i want check every array gpa = f/F use `in_array` or other function i don't use `foreach` `for`

```
Array
  (
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 5889
        [name] => Dom
        [student_id] => 2018000004
        [roll] => 1
        [class] => 6
        [department] => 
        [subject_type] => 0
        [subject_name] => 24
        [exam_type] => 1
        [exam_year] => 2018
        [full_mark] => 100
        [getmark] => 55
        [gpa] => F
        [log] => 2018-11-06 20:32:33
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 5890
        [name] => Rohim
        [student_id] => 2018000006
        [roll] => 1
        [class] => 6
        [department] => 
        [subject_type] => 0
        [subject_name] => 24
        [exam_type] => 1
        [exam_year] => 2018
        [full_mark] => 100
        [getmark] => 60
        [gpa] => 4
        [log] => 2018-11-05 19:42:26
    )
    )
```

i want to check .without any loop.

```
 if(in_array('F',$resultList)){
       echo "match";
     }else {
       echo "not match";
    }
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use a loop? You want to look for `"F"` in your array but there are objects in your array. Looping and checking each objects `->gpa` seems like a really simple way to check it.

Comment: You'll really need a loop for this. Why do you not want to use a loop?

Comment: ok. i want check only ` [gpa] => F`  or lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to know if there are any `F`'s in your array, you could use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
//Create an array of GPA's
$arr_gpa = array_column($array, 'gpa');

if(in_array('F', $arr_gpa)) {
    echo "match";
} else {
    echo "not match";
}
```

Comment: sure . need 2 min

Comment: @HasanSheikh Glad I could help!